# how to avoid non repetitive elements while writing to csv in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have the below function which finds out the date of the load and the sheet name , and i want this sheet name ->load_date to gets updated but it adds new row, so it is like add new key if not exists else update value of the same key, is there any way to fix this?

```
def func_append_load_date(df, 
                          sheet_name, 
                          path, 
                          input_thresh):
    """
    Function to update load date
    """
    thresh = 1 + input_thresh
    next_update_date = df['date'].iloc[df.shape[0] - thresh].date()
    print(path)
    with open(path, 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['dataset','load_date']
        file_is_empty = os.stat(path).st_size == 0
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if file_is_empty:
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'dataset':sheet_name, 'load_date':next_update_date})
```

current csv contains rows like if i ran it twice for 2 different sheet name:

```
original_building,1/12/2017
original_building,1/12/2017
original_building_2,3/12/2018
original_building_2,3/12/2018
```

expected csv:

```
original_building,1/12/2017
original_building_2,3/12/2018
```

Comment: Ussually csv files are comma seperated.

Comment: yes, just copy pasted the content as is , but this is comma seperated, changed it now

Comment: Are you sure func_append_load_date didn't get called twice for each sheet name somehow?